# showing user detail who has login

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a attendance page for internal use. now I encounter a problem which is only shows user detail who has login. could anyone improve the following script?

```
<?php

$query_RecBoards ="SELECT * FROM `attend` WHERE 
`m_username`='".$_SESSION["loginMember"]."' ORDER BY `m_time` DESC";
$RecBoards = mysql_query($query_RecBoards); 
$row_RecBoards = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecBoards);

$qry= "SELECT m_name, m_day, time_in, time_out, SEC_TO_TIME(
     CASE WHEN total_sec - 32400 > 0 
          THEN total_sec - 32400 
          ELSE 0 END) overtime,  
   SEC_TO_TIME(
     CASE WHEN total_sec - 32400 < 0 
          THEN 32400 - total_sec 
          ELSE 0 END) shorttime
  FROM
(
  SELECT m_name, m_day, time_in, time_out,
         TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(COALESCE(time_out, '17:30:00'),
                          COALESCE(time_in, '08:30:00'))) total_sec
    FROM
  (
   SELECT m_name, m_day, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN m_duty = 'Punchin' THEN m_time END) time_in,
       MIN(CASE WHEN m_duty = 'Punchout' THEN m_time END) time_out
      FROM attend
     GROUP BY m_name, m_day
  ) a
) b";
$result=mysql_query($qry);
?>
```

Henrik

Comment: The mysql_* extension that you've used was ***REMOVED*** from PHP version 7 so you should now be using either the mysqli_* extension or PDO. Always use prepared statements when plugging any external data into a query, no matter what the source and how well you trust the source, that way you don't risk accidentally opening up any security holes

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your advice, because I am using old version of PHP, that's why I am using old extension.

Finally, I figured out how to display the users who have logged in, but another question is how to display the data every month? any advice?

The improved part of code as following,

```
 SELECT m_name, m_day, 
         MIN(CASE WHEN m_duty = 'punchin' THEN m_time END) time_in,
         MIN(CASE WHEN m_duty = 'punchout' THEN m_time END) time_out
    FROM attend WHERE m_username='".$_SESSION["loginMember"]."'
   GROUP BY m_name, m_day
    )a  LIMIT 0,7
```

Thanks
Henrik